# C++ using GLFW, drawing triangle function acting weird with cout being commented out

Tags: c++, glfw, conan

I am new to programming in C++ and came across a problem in my function:

```
void render_triangle(float xs[3], float ys[3]) {
    /* Draw triangles based on coords */
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            // cout << xs[i];
            // cout << ' ';
            // cout << ys[i] << endl;
            glVertex2f(xs[i], ys[i]);
        }
    glEnd();
}
```

I am using GLFW, and the package manager Conan with CMake like in the example on the Conan documents. When the commented code is un-commented I get this behaviour, the rectangles are meant to be there its the triangle:

[image: Weird triangle]

However once I un-comment that cout code i get the expected behaviour which is:

[image: Expected triangle]

The input coords going to the function/the numbers getting printed out are as follows:

[image: {0.1, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.1, 0.2}]

This might be something really silly but I don't know how this behaviour is happening since only starting to learn C++ a few days ago, thanks for your help.

Comment: Uh, how that isxpected triangle if you have two points with same coordinates?

Comment: Hi sorry that was a typo in the text here but if you look at the image link it shows they are at diffrent coords :) The weird part is that the triangle changes when i print out the values

Comment: you have to learn how to debug and be sure rest of code is well-defined. That kind of effect is a typical sign of compiler optimization in case of Undefined  Behaviour.   outputting values may change as-if rule's effect on it. It's not possible to reproduce without complete program that shows this behaviour

Comment: Th github link is https://github.com/HarryBurge/CarConvoy if that is helpful at all

Comment: I also used this to do the package manager stuff https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: do you  get the wrong behavior when un-comment or comment cout ?

Comment: If you suspect there is something wrong in the package itself, I'd recommend to report in this repo: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index. So far, it looks more like a code issue in your side. It would also be good to report your platform, OS, compiler, compiler version. Make sure that you are building your code matching the Conan installation settings (default to Release, for example, if you are building debug, better use ``-s build_type=Debug``)

Comment: @OmarGhannou he gets expected output from adding output to `cout`, which paints the bug to be a "shroedinger" : it doesn't happen when you "look" at it.

Comment: I took a quick look at your repo and your `Obstacle` constructor is broken. It iterates `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){` but your arrays have only 3 elements

Comment: Out of curiosity, I clicked a bit through your git repo... @Swift suspected Undefined Behavior and I definitely found one occurrence in your code around: [for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {](https://github.com/HarryBurge/CarConvoy/blob/3a77a1d45b25bd7af1caf9f94bc28939e209cbf4/obstacle.cpp#L12). The ctor parameters are `float[3]` (which makes them pointers to `float` effectively). Then, there are the member vars. `float xs[3]; float ys[3];` but your loop runs `i` with 0 ... 3. That's an off-by-one-error and and out-of-bound access for read and write. Fix this and test again...

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, it now runs correctly thank you. Thank you everyone for taking the time to look into this for me, was baffled for a long time :)